# Return given String if it only contains certain chars

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to implement a method that checks a `String` for different things:
Firstly, the String has to look something like this:
`image/<subtype>`.
This means, the substring from the beginning until the 5th char has to be `image/`.
Also the `<subtype>` can only have 127 chars max. This can be tested by checking the complete `String` for a length no longer than 133 (as `image/` has 6 chars).
Now the substring from 6th char until the end of the complete String can be tested. It is only allowed to contain "a-z", "0-9" "-" and ".".
My method looks like this at the moment:

```
public static String requireValidImageMimeType(String mimeType){
    if(mimeType.length() > 133){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (mimeType.startsWith("image/")) {
        String mimeTypeToTest = mimeType.substring(6, mimeType.length());
        //TODO Create Regex Pattern
        if (mimeTypeToTest.matches("^[a-z0-9]+.+-")){
            return mimeType;
        }
    }
    return ??;
}
```

Are there any Regex pros out there?

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you want valid regex or handle `return ??` or something else?

Comment: What do you want to return is the string *doesn't* match?

Comment: Sorry, my explanation seems to be a bit unclear. The input String is supposed to be returned if it matches the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `^[a-z0-9]+.+-` with `^[-.a-z0-9]+"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex on match method:

```
image\\[a-z0-9-.]{0,127}
```

this should be: "image/anyletterswithmax127chars"

Comment: But this is missing out the "." and the "-" isn't it?

Comment: Oh sure, I was confused about the \w, updated with correct regex

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that in one regex :

```
^image/[a-z0-9.-]{0,127}$
```

You can test this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/n8q5X1/5)

Comment: the slash has no special meaning in regex, so no need to escape it. some languages delimit the entire regex with slashes, but java is not one of those languages

Comment: Shouldn't the `-` literal inside bracket expression, be the first character of the expression(to be safe)?

Comment: @boob yes - `-` should be either first or last or escaped when used as a literal in a character class

Comment: Updated to make it safer